# What device can I get or configure that extends existing WiFi networks without creating new ones?

Tags: wifi, networking

[This may be the wrong SE site for this question. Apologies if it is: it seems the best fit.]

I have ongoing problems with WiFi connectivity in my house. Due to a combination of factors, my router sits at probably the least convenient spot in the entire building and it's hard to see how it could go elsewhere.

We're using the default free router that came with the network, and I'd prefer not to change it. Good routers seem very expensive. And, after a bad experience trying to borrow a better router to see if improved things, I don't really want the hassle.

I understand that there are a variety of devices that can help with this. For maximum convenience, however, I want something that will extend the range of the *same network*. We use mobile devices a lot, and wandering around with one switching between networks based on strength is problematic.

I understood that the way to do this was to get a "range extender" as opposed to a repeater or power line adapter, which create new network names you can feed off. To this end I got a D-Link 1320. However, when I plugged it in, it created a new network with a new network name. Trialing it proved as problematic as I expected and we soon turned it off.

The question then is: first, is it possible to get a device that increases the range of the *same network* and doesn't do so by creating a new network name for devices to log on to? Second, if so, will my D-Link 1320 do this? Third, if not, what device can you recommend that will?

Comment: Your 1320 should do what you want, just glancing at the setup doc.  Please review it and confirm you have set it up correctly. http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DAP-1320

Comment: Some sort of whole home WiFi system could do this. See this question: https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7700/whole-home-wifi-system